# Solving a linear system of equations with nonlinear constraints

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I have a system of 6 equations for 8 variables.  There are many solutions.  I want a solution that minimizes $x_1^2 + x_2^2 + ... + x_8^2$.

Is there a formulaic method to solve this?

(Application: 8 motors in an octocopter.  Thrust and torque for each motor is approximately linear with throttle/RPM.  Power consumption is quadratic with respect to throttle.  Achieve a given combined thrust+torque, with minimal power.)

Comment: Could u mention the 6 others?

Comment: the other 6 others form a normal linear system of equations

Comment: The Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse is [precisely what you need](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Minimum_norm_solution_to_a_linear_system).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wish to find the solution to the linear system $Ax=b$ with minimal norm, $\|x\|_2$. Assuming the rows of $A$ are linearly independent, this problem has a unique solution. The solution to this problem is given by $x = A^+b$, where $A^+$ is the [Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse) of $A$. You matrix $A$ has more columns than rows. Assuming the rows are linearly independent, the pseudo-inverse can be written as $$A^+ = A^T(AA^T)^{-1},$$ where $A^T$ denotes the matrix transpose of $A$. There are routines to compute this in more stable ways in basically all linear algebra libraries.

Comment: +1 If $AA^\top$ is not invertible, then your rows are not linearly dependent, i.e. you have equations providing redundant information. If this is a problem, try row reducing $A$ first and removing zero rows, before applying this method.

Comment: I believe that if you use a library calling LAPACK (most of them) then it will be constructed using the SVD and will avoid this potential issue.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer.  I'd like to learn more about these things, but Wikipedia seems like more of a reference.  Can you recommend a book or other resource where I can learn about this comprehensively?

Comment: It is covered in most linear algebra textbooks that aren't too theoretical. Matrix Computations by Golub and Van Loan is a standard reference, although a bit heavy.